# Java swing autocomplete list refresh on event

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

I have to create autocomplete feature in my search combo box. For that I have create and editable combobox and added Document listener on that. Every time when someone type anything, I am sending request to solr server and updating combo box list with response coming from solr server.  My problem is I want to refresh the combo box with new response for that I am removing all item from combobox and adding them with new response coming but it’s not working. Sample code is as below

```
    SearchComboField = new JComboBox();
    final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    SearchComboField.setEditable(true);
    JTextComponent editorComponent = (JTextComponent) SearchComboField.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    Document document = editorComponent.getDocument();
    document.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("insertUpdate");
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("changedUpdate");
        }

        public void update() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    model.removeAllElements();
                    //I will add Server response here   
                    model.addElement("One");
                }

            });
        }
    });
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(SearchComboField);
```

Comment: *"but it’s not working"* ... which part?

Comment: Unable to select item from combo box drop down, removeAllElements() is also creating an event which again fire a request to solr server.

Comment: DocumentListener isn't designated for changes to itslef, current Document, or required another workaround, for why reason you broken autocomplete in SwingXs AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
JComboBox SearchComboField = new JComboBox(model);
```

Comment: I used the code in suggested way but it causing infinite loop and I am unable to select my item from list. 

removeAllElements() is again firing an event which is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: I have not compiled and run the full code. let me check.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. I will check.Also you can take the approach given here: <http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html>

Comment: Thanks for above example but here data is loaded at initialization and i have to add the data at run time every time when user is typing anything in combo box.